# Should I keep or remove the title for this form?

Tags: forms, ios, login, popup, modal-windows

As the Log In button is in the toolbar the title seems like repetition.

**Do I keep (A) or remove (B) the title Log In?**

Or do I change the title and/or button text?

[image]
*Screenshots from an iPhone 6S but this is also supported on iPad*

Answer (score 3):

The [iOS HCI Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Modal.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH64-SW1) suggest that you should follow the Modal View in order to have the user complete a task and have complete knowledge of the task they are doing.

Although the button suffices the purpose of the *context*, I would still recommend using the title to adhere to the guidelines. iOS users are accustomed to the layout and know the difference between the **Title** and the **Action**.

If you still are hesitant to do this, you could simply rename the title to **"Login to Dave's App"**

[image: modal view]

Comment: completely agree, I've read through the guidelines hence my hesitation to remove it. But... at present it doesn't seem right when it is the same text as the action. serious comment here... if I rename it to "Log In to Dave's App" there won't be room for it (on most iPhones anyway). the real name of the app is longer than Dave's App btw. what is your suggestion for the title text now based on this comment?

Comment: If you want to remove the redundancy, you can rename the action button to "Submit" or something other than "Log In". I agree you should keep the title as well.

Comment: Great suggestion @ryancdotnet. I suggested the title for the app name since it even gives the user the context of which app he's in.